# How to Tap Windows 8 Phone to a POS NFC Reader

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nfc

I would like to use my NFC phone to tap against an NFC reader. Basically the phone will act as an NFC tag and will pass the NDEF message  to the NFC reader. The idea behind it is that I can build an APP that will specify the NDEC message I want to pass to the NFC Reader.

Example:

URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

I will have my app that has saved this URI. I will tap my phone against the NFC Reader and the reader will be able to read the NDEF message from my phone.

Anyone that knows about this and could give me some direction will be much appreciate it, thanks.  This behavior supposed to work fine with NFC payments but I believe that with NFC payments, we need to have a secure NFC SIM card so we can be able to store in the secure element. I am using Nokia Lumia 620.

Answer (score 0):

Add your app to wallet, and make people pay it from there. I think that this'll work, just do it like banks ;).
See this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Wallet-payment-instruments-85c2a7a0